# Table collection from real table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have next table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  age NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
);
```

I want to create Table collection from my_table. Fill it my data.

I try:

```
DECLARE  
  type my_type IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;
  my_data my_type := my_type();
BEGIN
  my_data := my_type('1','Jon',5);
END;
```

As result i get:

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 16:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my_type'
ORA-06550: line 8, column 16:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my_type'
ORA-06550: line 8, column 16:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my_type'
```

How to create array items of analog my table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE  
  type my_type IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;
  my_data my_type := my_type();
  idx number;
BEGIN

  my_data.extend(1);
  idx := my_data.count;
  my_data(idx).id := 1;
  my_data(idx).name := 'John';
  my_data(idx).age := 5;


END;
```

or

```
DECLARE  
  type my_type IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;
  my_data my_type := my_type();
  rec  my_table%ROWTYPE;
  idx number;
BEGIN

  my_data.extend(1);
  idx := my_data.count;
  rec.id := 1;
  rec.name := 'John';
  rec.agr := 5;
  my_data(idx) := rec;


END;
```

Comment: Thanks! And how i can print my_data ?

Comment: @ks_on_v Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT()` or `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` and string concatenation Something like: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( my_data(1).id || ',' || my_data(1).name )`

Comment: But how i use it in script:
  type my_type IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;

  var my_data my_type;
  my_data := my_type();
  var rec  my_table%ROWTYPE;
  var idx number;

  my_data.extend(1);
  idx := my_data.count;
  rec.id := 1;
  rec.name := 'John';
  rec.id := 'Age';
  my_data(idx) := rec;

Comment: Yes, you shoudl open sql Worksheet insert script and use button  "run scirpt' not "run statment". But i'm not sure i'm not using sqldevleper from ages

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz just a little correction : `my_data(idx).age := 5;` for rows related to `age`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you populate the `collection` made of a `table` type in `plSQL` block:

```
 DECLARE
       TYPE my_type IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;

       my_data   my_type := my_type ();
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO my_table
        VALUES ('1', 'Jon', 5);

        COMMIT;

       SELECT *
         BULK COLLECT INTO my_data
         FROM my_table;

       for i in 1..my_data.count
       loop
        dbms_output.put_line(my_data(i).id);
       end loop;

    END

;
```